# verify solution to first order quasi linear pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

question is, $u^2u_x+u_y = u$ and Initial value is $u(x,0)=x$ where $y \gt 0$

my solution is $x=u^2(y+(u/e^y))$

Answer (score 1):

$$u^2u_x+u_y = u \quad\text{ and Initial value is }\quad u(x,0)=x$$
My answer as terse as the question is :
$$x-e^{-y}u-(1-e^{-2y})\frac{u^2}{2}=0$$
Solving this quadratic equation for $u$ leads to $u(x,y)$.